# How to stop images from affecting other images in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image, quantization

I'm writing a piece of code, in Python, to show image quantization (2,4,6,8 - Level).
I'm using matplotlib, skimage and numpy.
The code was running as expected for the individual levels, but when I tried to club them all into one program, the image produced first seems to affect the ones after it.

I have used separate arrays for the different levels and have assigned them separately but nothing changed.

I also tried using separate values for each snippet but to no avail.

The only thing I have noticed is that when I write the code from 2-8 level instead of 8-2 level, the images turn out different. It is from here that I deduced that somehow, despite being declared separately, the transformations are being made on the previous image rather than the original image.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Original Image
i = io.imread('A1.jpg')
plt.subplot(3, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(i)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("Original")

#Grayscale
iG1 = color.rgb2gray(i)
(r,c) = iG1.shape
plt.subplot(3, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(iG1, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("Grayscale")

iG8 = iG1
iG6 = iG1
iG4 = iG1
iG2 = iG1 

#8-Level Quantization
for i8 in range(0,r):
    for j8 in range(0,c):
        f8 = iG8[i8,j8]
        if f8<=0.125:
            iG8[i8,j8] = 0
        elif f8>0.125 and f8<=0.25:
            iG8[i8,j8] = 0.1875
        elif f8>0.25 and f8<=0.375:
            iG8[i8,j8] = 0.3125
        elif f8>0.375 and f8<=0.5:
            iG8[i8,j8] = 0.4375
        elif f8>0.5 and f8<=0.625:
            iG8[i8,j8] = 0.5625
        elif f8>0.625 and f8<=0.75:
            iG8[i8,j8] = 0.687
        elif f8>0.75 and f8<=0.875:
            iG8[i8,j8] = 0.8125 
        elif f8>0.875 and f8<=1.0:
            iG8[i8,j8] = 1
            
plt.subplot(3, 2, 3)
plt.imshow(iG8, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("8-Level Quantization") 

#6-Level Quantization
for i6 in range(0,r):
    for j6 in range(0,c):
        f6 = iG6[i6,j6]
        if f6<=0.16:
            iG6[i6,j6] = 0
        elif f6>0.16 and f6<=0.32:
            iG6[i6,j6] = 0.24
        elif f6>0.32 and f6<=0.48:
            iG6[i6,j6] = 0.4
        elif f6>0.48 and f6<=0.64:
            iG6[i6,j6] = 0.56
        elif f6>0.64 and f6<=0.8:
            iG6[i6,j6] = 0.72
        elif f6>0.8 and f6<=1.0:
            iG6[i6,j6] = 1
            
plt.subplot(3, 2, 4)
plt.imshow(iG6, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("6-Level Quantization")

#4-Level Quantization
for i4 in range(0,r):
    for j4 in range(0,c):
        f4 = iG4[i4,j4]
        if f4<=0.25:
            iG4[i4,j4] = 0
        elif f4>0.25 and f4<=0.50:
            iG4[i4,j4] = 0.25
        elif f4>0.50 and f4<=0.75:
            iG4[i4,j4] = 0.75
        elif f4>0.75 and f4<=1.0:
            iG4[i4,j4] = 1
            
plt.subplot(3, 2, 5)
plt.imshow(iG4, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("4-Level Quantization")  

#2-Level Quantization
for i2 in range(0,r):
    for j2 in range(0,c):
        f2 = iG2[i2,j2]
        if f2<=0.50:
            iG2[i2,j2] = 0
        elif f2>0.50:
            iG2[i2,j2] = 1

plt.subplot(3, 2, 6)
plt.imshow(iG2, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("2-Level Quantization")
```

This code gives me the output:
[8-2Level Quantization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL2ME.png)

My problem is that the images are being affected by the transformations done on the previous image, clearly demonstrated by this output: [2-8Level Quantization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPokk.png)

The actual images should look like this: [2Level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbVa9.png) [4Level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocAGa.png) [6Level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9OYB.png) [8Level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e0Ao.png)

Comment: `iG8 = iG1`, `iG6 = iG1` etc. means that `iG8`, `iG6`, `iG4` and `iG2` all point to the same object that `iG1` points to. You're not copying it, you're just creating multiple references to the same object. Therefore, changing any of those objects will affect all the others since they're all the same one.

Comment: just want to point out that you can avoid your `if/else` statements inside your nested loops and the nested loops themselves with `numpy.select`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RandomDavis Oh!!! Okay so, how do I make unique copies of iG1? Is there a specific to declare for such usage?

Comment: @PaulH Thanks for your feedback! I'm fairly new to numpy and learning stuff like this is gold :) I'll try to learn about and use numpy.select from here on! Cheers!

Comment: "how do I make unique copies" Use `image2 = np.copy(image1)`, for example